# Not defined state of the `Network security: Restrict NTLM: NTLM authentication in this domain` GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2019, ntlm

Is NTLM by default disabled on domain controllers with Windows Server 2019?

My current tests show that the GPO [Network security: Restrict NTLM: NTLM authentication in this domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-restrict-ntlm-ntlm-authentication-in-this-domain) does not work as documented. When this GPO is Not defined, NTLM does not work, and I see errors in Windows Security log:

```
Status: 0x80090302
Sub Status: 0xC0000418
```

Status 0xC0000418 [translates to `STATUS_NTLM_BLOCKED` (The authentication failed because NTLM was blocked)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55).

However, if I change GPO to Disable, NTLM works again.

The documentation says that when "Not defined" "The domain controller **will allow all NTLM authentication requests** in the domain where the policy is deployed.". So I was assuming that I don't need to change group policies to enable NTLM.

OS Name Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard

Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763

Comment: Did you check Default Domain Policy and Default Domain Domain Controllers Policy? Group Policy Modeling wizard may be also helpfull to find actual applied policy.

Comment: I've checked with GPRESULT and gpmc and now I don't see any relevant security policies enabled (i.e. defined). I see only these two: `Network security: Do not store LAN Manager hash value on next password change Enabled` and  
`Network security: Force logoff when logon hours expire Disabled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked that the server computers had a Local Security Policy that disabled NTLM. NTLM works again after removing this policy.